# Is there an option to show a larger message by bitbucketCloud on Slack

Tags: bitbucket, slack, bitbucket-cloud

The issue Im having is that the messages post in Slack by Bitbucket Cloud seem shortened. I would like to receive the full pull request description in slack, it only posts the 5 most recent commits while I would like to see all commits and their messages.

I've already asked this on bitbucket forums but Ive gotten no response yet. (https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-cloud-on-slack-shortens-message/qaq-p/1514370)